# Linq-to-NHibernate OrderBy Not Working

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm trying order a Linq to NHibernate query.

```
                var clients = (from c in session.QueryOver<Clients>()
                 orderby c.Nom
                 select c
                ).List();
```

It doesn't work : List() isn't an existing method.
It works if I write that :

```
            var clients2 = (from c in session.QueryOver<Clients>()
             orderby c.Nom
             select c
            );
            var clients3 = clients2.Asc.List();
```

There is a difference if orderby is used or not.
In the previous code, the clients2 type is NHibernate.Criterion.Lambda.IQueryOverOrderBuilder.

```
            var clients4 = (from c in session.QueryOver<Clients>()
             select c
            );
```

In this case clients4's type is NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver.
Does someone know this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QueryOver is not the LINQ API. You should use the Query extension method instead.

```
var clients = (from c in session.Query<Clients>()
                orderby c.Nom
                select c
               ).List();
```

**Update**

```
using NHibernate.Linq;
```

Comment: I already heard of the Query method of the ISession class but the Intellisence doesn't find it. In my project I made references to all the required dll.

Comment: It's not in the NHibernate namespace. I believe it's in NHibernate.Linq.

Comment: well I don't find it. In all the example it should be in the ISession object, maybe it's deprecated in nhibernate 3 ?

Comment: It's an extension method that is new in NH3.  In the previous version it was a separate assembly and the method was named Linq.  I have edited the answer with the using statement you need to add to the source.

Comment: Well I found it. I didn't add using NHibernate.Linq and after that it works. Thank you